Restrict AWS X-ray trace logging for /health check in Quarkus Java
Requirement is to disable health checks for /health in Quarkus framework. I have tried to configure manually using sampling settings in AWS account and it did not work. I also added following code as well which did not pick up and saw errors while compile. Any help is appreciated. Want to know if any coding is needed or config is fine. I am working on this one first time.
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda-xray</artifactId>
</dependency>

application.properties
quarkus.amazon-xray.enabled=true
quarkus.amazon-xray.service-name=api-name 
quarkus.amazon-xray.sampling-rules-path=/xray-sampling-rules.json 

<quarkus-plugin.version>2.16.7.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
<quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
<quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
<quarkus.platform.version>2.16.7.Final</quarkus.platform.version>

While compile I get the following:
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.amazon-xray.sampling-rules-path" was provided; it will be ignored; verify tha
t the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the 
dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.amazon-xray.enabled" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the depend
ency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo

xray-sampling-rules.json
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Health check path",
      "service_name": "*",
      "http_method": "*",
      "host": "*",
      "resource_arn": "*",
      "priority": 1,
      "fixed_target": 0,
      "rate": 0.0,
      "url_path": "/v1/health/"
    }
  ],
  "default": {
    "fixed_target": 1,
    "rate": 0.05
  }
}


You can initialize xray with customized local sampling rule by
xRayInitializer.withSamplingStrategy(new LocalizedSamplingStrategy(new URL( "file:" + getSamplingStrategy(logger))));
